# How to edit ingress hosts?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I've deployed Harbor on my K8S cluster as follows:

```
helm install dockistry harbor/harbor \
  --set expose.type=ingress
```

Then the ingress ressource shows:

```
kubectl get ingress
NAME                       HOSTS                                     ADDRESS          PORTS     AGE
dockistry-harbor-ingress   core.harbor.domain,notary.harbor.domain   xxx.xxx.100.61   80, 443   2m43s
```

The `HOSTS` is wrong and would like to change it. How can I edit `dockistry-harbor-ingress` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
kubectl edit ingress dockistry-harbor-ingress
```

will open up an editor where you can edit and then save it which automatically applies the change to the cluster.

Alternatively you can `kubectl get ingress dockistry-harbor-ingress --export -o yaml > ingress.yaml` to save in a yaml and edit it and then apply it via `kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml`